# Wrap Scene tabs with component react-native react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a tabbar component rendered within  which I want to wrap with a custom native module for a custom style behavior not available within react's css (linear opacity gradience.)

```
  <Scene key="video" tabs={true} tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle}>
    <Scene key="profile" title="profile" component={MyProfile} icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar />
    <Scene key="trend" title="trend" component={TrendMenuScene} icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar />
    <Scene key="home" title="home" component={MainMenuScene} initial icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar />
    <Scene key="star" title="star" component={Favourite} icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar />
    <Scene key="discover" title="discover" component={Search} icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar />
  </Scene>
```

My first attempt and thought would be to add a component attribute to the top level that wraps the scene component. inside that component might be something like.

```
return (
        <LinearGradient key="gradientWrap" colors={['transparent', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
        {this.props.children}
        </LinearGradient>
    )
```

this does not work and throws a error. I have tried cloning props but I wrap everything and the entire pages is wrapped in the linear gradient :/

So how to wrap just the tabbar in the linear gradient? Or more generally any wrapping component.